# VB how to copy a sheet from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble copying a sheet from one workbook to another using visual basic.

My code so far opens up a blank workbook and it opens up another excel file with the sheet I want to copy over. Here's what I got:

```
    'This creates the new workbook
    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    NewBook.Title = MyRecordset.Fields(1) & "_Tables"
    'This creates a sheet named "2-13"
    Sheets.Add().name = "2-13"   

    'This will open up the existing excel file with the sheet i want to copy over
    Set XlApp = New Excel.Application

    XlApp.Visible = True

    XlApp.Workbooks.Open (CurrentProject.Path & "\Charts\" & MyRecordset.Fields(1) & "_Charts")
    Set wBook = XlApp.Workbooks(XlApp.Workbooks.Count)

    Set wSheet2 = wBook.Sheets("L1")
```

So, NewBook is the blank excel file and wBook is the excel file that has the Sheet called "L1" that I want to copy over to NewBook in the sheet called "2-13". Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) the contents of one worksheet to another:

```
' Get contents of worksheet.
wBook.Sheets("L1").UsedRange.Copy

' Paste contents into new sheet.
NewBook.Sheets("2-13").Paste
```